# Jacobi Symbol walk through questions

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

I am reading the book **Introduction to Modern Cryptography** second edition by Katz et al.

The Jacobi Symbol is defined on **page 536** and I have included a picture below.

I was able to understand most of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulgi9xlqzw8) on solving Jacobi Symbol equations. Provided this is not off topic to what the book requires, I have some questions about some of the different examples from the video.

1. **1:14** Why did he flip the fraction here, take away one, and then divide?
2. **2:28** If the top (called 'a') is a number that can be expressed as a square, then it equals 1? Why did he not flip the fraction like he earlier at **1:14**?

I think the answer for the above question 1 and 2 is you only flip it when there is not a number at the top which can be the product of a square?

3. **4:51** Why is this answer -1, I thought 2 (mod 3) = 2?
4. I did think when using Jacobi Symbols the top number had to be larger than the bottom number, but it does not always seem to be the case here?

The above questions I have seem to happen throughout the video, so I will avoid asking the same question numerous times.

[image: crypto book]

Comment: What do you mean by "flipping the fraction"?  As far as I can tell he just went from the Legendre symbol 11 on 5 to the Legendre symbol 1 on 5 (which is just because it just depends on what the top number is modulo the bottom number)

Comment: @babu_babu By flipping I mean: (a/p) = a^((p - 1)/2)

Comment: Isn't that a general fact about the Legendre symbol? It is called Euler's criterion. Do you know why it is true?

Comment: I really have no idea what I am doing, aside from some elementary modulus like 1 mod 2 = 1 etc... If someone could just walk me through with an answer, and then highlight when the process changes, why an answer is +1, -1, or 0 I would be eternally grateful. I have been stuck on this for several days now.

Comment: Okay, well the justification for (1) is that it is Euler's criterion (you can look that up on Wikipedia or prove it yourself from the definitions). The justification for (2) is that it is the definition of the Legendre symbol (but you could also use Euler's criterion if you wanted). The justification for (3) is that 2 and -3 are congruent mod 3, and Euler's criterion only tells you what the Legendre symbol is modulo p. The justification for (4) is again the definition of the Legendre symbol.

Comment: do you know the definition of the Legendre symbol? I think that your issues would be resolved if you learned that and figured out / looked up the proof of Euler's criterion.